# Making Eclipse behave like Visual Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, visual-studio, ide

I'm doing some Android development, and I much prefer Visual Studio, but I'll have to use *Eclipse* for this.

Has anyone made a tool which can make *Eclipse* look and behave more like visual studio? I mainly can't stand its **clippyesqe** suggestions on how I should program (Yes, I know I have not yet used that private field! Thanks Eclipse!), or its incredibly lousy **intellisense**.

For example, in eclipse, if I don't type `this` first, its **intellisense** won't realise I want to look for locally scoped members. Also, the TAB to complete VS convention is drilled into my head, and *Eclipse* is ENTER to complete, I could switch everything by hand but that would take hours, and I was hoping someone had some sort of theme or something that has already done it.

Comment: "in eclipse, if I don't type "this" first, its intellisense won't realize I want to look for locally scoped members"

Um, yes it does.

Comment: My version doesn't, perhaps its a configuration issue.

Comment: Easiest way to make Eclipse like VS: Uninstall debugger, use only Navigator instead of Project Viewer, hide every single tab at the bottom, randomly spread keyboard shortcuts all around the keyboard. Done! :(

Comment: Hey guys. I have written an article on what I did to make Eclipse both look and work more like VS: http://www.jackyliang.com/jackybegincoding/2014/4/5/make-eclipse-work-more-like-visual-studio Feel free to check it out. I am sure I share a lot of your frustrations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are also other choices for Java IDEs.  You've obviously found Eclipse, but you also may want to check out [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/index.html) and [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/).  IntelliJ is not free, but has a 30 day evaluation period and a Visual Studio key map :)

Shop around, find one that you like and start to use it heavily.  They are all very good IDEs, and I'm sure once you use one for a while you'll get comfortable with it.

Comment: Eclipse is the only IDE with support for the Android plugin, I could adapt Visual Studio to work with Android with the same amount of effort it would take to do IntelliJ or NetBeans.

Comment: There is an Android Plugin for IntelliJ.  http://code.google.com/p/idea-android/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: There is also an Android plugin for NetBeans. http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroAndroidDevNetBeans

Comment: The IntellIJ plugin looks like it may be suffering from bit rot.  It hasn't been updated for the recent Android releases :(. (See the comments and the end of the getting started page) You might have better luck starting with NetBeans.

Comment: Note that IntelliJ 9 has an open-source community version, which can be acquired free of charge.

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried using the Visual Studio keybindings available in Eclipse Ganymede (3.4)?

(You may want to know that "IntelliSense" is a Visual Studio-term, an probably unknown to anyone without Visual Studio-experience. "Autocompletion" is probably a more widely used term.)

Comment: You also need the C++ development tools installed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200499/visual-studios-keybindings-for-eclipse/544635#544635

Comment: Three years later, playing with Eclipse for the first time, it should be noted that this is still true: Eclipse (now on Indigo) still only comes with "default" and "emacs" keybindings. Installed the c++ development tools (from Help->"Install new software"), the VS keybindings became available (from Window->Preferences->General->Keys). Eclipse puts things in weird places... definitely not the menus I would've expected either of those commands to be found.

Answer (score 6):

If you start typing the name of any class/variable visible in the current scope and hit Ctrl+Space, it'll bring down the autocompletion.

By default, tab is used to move around autocompleted function call arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna play devils advocate here and say that forcing you to use `this.myString` is actually much safer than just `myString`. `myString` could be defined locally (in the method) or in the class as a private member. I sometimes think Visual Studio is a bit cavalier about this. In the sample you mention (I saw the video but it was illegible) where is `myString` scoped?