# Visual Studio's keybindings for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Does anybody have a keybinding scheme similar to VS 2005 available for Eclipse?

How to import it into preferences of Eclipse (I see only export button).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

**How to Install Visual Studio Key Bindings in Eclipse (Helios onwards)**

For anyone finding this post, if you need step by step instructions and you're using Eclipse Indigo PDT , the following should help you:

(Note: you will be prompted to restart Eclipse after installing)

1. Start Eclipse
2. Click **Help** -> **Install New Software**
3. In the **Work with** box select or type your [version of Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Older_Versions_Of_Eclipse), e.g.:

   - for [Neon (4.6)](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/)
   - for [Mars (4.5)](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/)
   - for [Luna (4.4)](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna)
   - for [Kepler (4.3)](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler)
   - for [Juno (4.2)](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno)
   - for [Indigo (3.7)](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo)
   - for [Helios (3.6)](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios)
4. Make sure the 'type filter text' box is blank.
5. Wait for a list of names and versions to appear
6. Scroll down to find **Programming Languages**, and expand it
7. Locate **C/C++ Development Tools** and check the box
8. Click **Next** and follow the remaining instructions on screen.

After finishing the install and restarting Eclipse...

1. Click Window -> Preferences
2. Expand General
3. Click Keys
4. Change the Scheme drop down to Microsoft Visual Studio
5. Click OK

To confirm the update, try pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and the 'Search' dialogue box should appear.

Comment: Other versions at: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler (4.3), http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno (4.2).
Note that these shortcuts only apply to the **C++-files**, so if you want to navigate/edit a **Java project** with VS-shortcuts, this is **not the solution**.

Comment: @YahooSerious Thanks for the additional versions, I've updated my answer. The rest of your comment is not quite right. The shortcuts do work with other files (not just C++ files) - I use them with PHP files / projects, for example.

Comment: I really wanted this option. But after setting Visual Studio key bindings scheme and testing it for a while, I rolled back to Eclipse scheme... for 2 reasons: Missing some important VS shortcuts (e.g. F12!) and hidden some important Eclipse shortcuts (e.g. Ctrl+Shift+F, F3). So, imho the best choice is to learn Eclipse shortcuts and add some necessary VS ones.

Comment: @ZbigniewWiadro you can tweak the key-bindings as you want to by going to Window > Preferences > General > Keys.

Comment: @Chris I knew that and by this I ment "add some necessary VS shortcuts". In Eclipse F3 is go to definition/declaration, as I remember.

Answer (score 19):

I think the latest Eclipse ships with Visual Studio bindings but at least the Eclipse PDT doesn't (which I just installed). And I would prefer to not have lots of extra plug-ins in Eclipse to keep it more "slim", so I didn't add the C++ plug-in. (maybe it doesn't affect performance but I really need only the keys...)

So anyway, I added the keys which I needed. As previous posters noted, when you "Export" in the key customization there is no way to import them, so the separate File->Export/Import functionality is the way to go.

So, as summary:

1. Try add to Eclipse C++ plugin and see if it ships with key bindings that work for you
2. Use mine key bindings, key list and download [here](http://code.vn720.com/2009/10/02/visual-studio-key-bindings-for-eclipse)
   install: unzip, use File->Import->General... to get it to Eclipse

It's far from complete of course (it's only keys which I missed to get started...), but better than nothing anyway.

Update (2009-10-16): Added <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (go-to-line) to the bindings.

Comment: The file download is not working. Is there an update somewhere?

Comment: I found something similar: https://gist.github.com/htsign/580099c7ae1173e048c2d98b4ce01661#file-keybindingslikevs-epf

Answer (score 18):

To get the Visual Studio key bindings in Eclipse you need to install the C++ development plugins - see [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-ganymede/).

I downloaded the latest Java development version of Eclipse (version below), when to Help -> Software Updates -> Available Software -> Ganymede and ticked the C++ box. After a restart the Visual Studio key binding appeared in the list.

```
Eclipse Platform

Version: 3.4.1
Build id: M20080911-1700
```

Comment: Gift that keeps on giving.  This trick worked with Galileo today.  Ahhhhhh, ctrl-tab.

Comment: That is beauty to my constitution. Just did it for Indigo - had to add the site  to eclipse under Help > Add/Update for CDT at http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/ - then installed CDT Main tools from it. Visual Studio bindings became available under Windows >Prefs >  General Keys

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a VS2005 keybinding scheme as I personally prefer a Brief-style scheme.

However, to import "it", as far as I know (at least on Eclipse 3.4 Ganymede) use File -> Import -> General -> Preferences where "it" is a .prf file which has been saved out using File -> Export -> General -> Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Ganymede has a built-in keybinding scheme for Visual Studio. Have you tried that?

Comment: In which build ? I have Eclipse Platform Version: 3.4.0 Build id: I20080617-2000 and no VS bindigs built-in ...

Comment: I haven't checked the build number. Are we really looking in the same place?