# Visual Studio-like Aptana key bindings

Tags: visual-studio, macos, aptana

Does anybody know how I can set a new scheme for my keyboard shortcuts that mimics the default key bindings of MS Visual Studio?

There are two default schemes in Aptana (Preferences | General | Keys) but can I create or (better still) upload a new scheme?

Ideally I'd like to avoid having to set them all manually.

I'm on a OS X Snow Leopard, btw.

Cheers
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99% of the key bindings should be for native Eclipse functionality, so you could find a Visual Studio-like keybinding for Eclipse, and that should work for Aptana. Someone posted something like that here:

[Visual Studio's keybindings for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200499/visual-studios-keybindings-for-eclipse/544635#544635)

And that should work if you can import the scheme the top responder has offered.

Best,
Ingo