# Does Eclipse support keyboard shortcuts known from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, keyboard

First, I know it is possible to setup Visual Studio keyboard scheme in Eclipse after installing CDT plugin, but unfortunately most useful keys only work with C/C++ sources, not with Java.

I'm trying to configure Java editor but I'm unable to find some of most useful shortcuts...

Go to declaration (VS: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) / go to definition... (VS: <kbd>F12</kbd>) / Go back (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num*</kbd>)
Quick identifier under cursor search (VS: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>)
Code autoformat (VS: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>)
Quickly set anonymous bookmark (VS: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) / Go to next bookmark (VS: <kbd>F2</kbd>)

Probably more to come :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200499/visual-studios-keybindings-for-eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t76435.rhtml

"... you can display a list of all the hotkeys in Eclipse using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+L</kbd> .

... It's possible to customize the hotkeys in Eclipse through Window->Preferences...->General->Keys. "

**Edit:** Some of the ones you are looking for include:

- Format = <kbd>Ctrl+Shft+F</kbd>
- Open declaration = <kbd>F3</kbd>
- Last edit location = <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd>
- Go back = <kbd>Alt+Left</kbd>
- Next annotation(bookmark) = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>
- Previous annotation(bookmark) = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

You can set a hotkey for new bookmark in the keys menu.

Annotations can include bookmarks if you check them on the drop down menu.

Hopefully that helps a little.

Comment: I know how to customize and view active shortcuts, but I can't see ones I need. Maybe I'm missing them, or maybe I need some plugin to do what I want...

Comment: To clarify for future people like me: "check them on the drop down menu" refers to the dropdown menu on the Next/Previous Annotation buttons on the toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

The best approximation to Visual Studio's bookmarks (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> = set, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> = next, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> = previous) that I've found is:

1. Set a keyboard shortcut for adding a bookmark. `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys`. (I used <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> from habit.) See also this [blog post](http://sandarenu.blogspot.com/2008/02/using-bookmarks-in-eclipse.html). Unfortunately I don't see any way to have anonymous shortcuts, you must type a name. (Edit: After using it for a while I find named bookmarks are quite a bit more useful than anonymous, and the currently selected word will be automatically used for the bookmark name so little typing is necessary.)
2. As Andres said, select `Bookmarks` in the drop-down menu of your Next Annotation button on the toolbar.
3. Now you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to move between bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys -> Scheme (dropdown) -> Microsoft Visual Studio

You get almost all Visual Studio shortcuts on a silver palate.

Comment: This isn't present in all eclipse versions.. You need to add C/c++ development plugin and even then, only a handful of keys are mapped