# Which flavor of eclipse to download in order to start developing with GWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am new to the world of Java and web programming. Never wrote a single line of javascript and my knowledge of HTML is pretty basic. Although, I am very experienced with .NET, so I guess transition to Java should not be a revolution.

Anyway, I wish to learn GWT and for that I want to work on Eclipse (I have Mac at home, so no Visual Studio).

Now, there are a dozen different download flavors of Eclipse, so my question is - which one best suits my needs?

Thanks.

**P.S.**

This is probably not a factor in the decision, but I will need Visual Studio keyboard bindings. I want to believe that no matter which flavor I install, I will be able to change the keyboard bindings later.

Comment: *"Dear ladies and sirs."* - You what?  That's so 19th century!  (But at least you didn't sign off with "your humble servant" ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be fine with any version of Eclipse. Eclipse is extremely modular so it's only really a case of ensuring you have the correct plugins installed.

I'd recommend:

- Start with the [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr1) as a base install. This has everything you need for Java (i.e. the Java Development Tools, stndard editor features, source code control etc.)
- Then install the [GWT plugin for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/eclipse/)

After that you should be good to go. If you find you need more plugins later, you can easily add them.

I also know both .NET and Java, and you should not have have much difficulty making the transition - it's really just a case of learning a few slightly different conventions, APIs and ways of doing things.

With regards to the keyboard bindings, I've never really changed from the default settings myself but they are completely customizable so I'm sure you can get it set up how you want. You might want to look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200499/visual-studios-keybindings-for-eclipse), which give you a few options (apparently you can download the full set of bindings, or install the C++ plugin which includes them).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start by installing [Eclipse for Java EE developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php) and then the GWT plugin. It will cause less dependencies to be installed and you will get some things installed that you will probably want to start using later. But regardless of whether you are using that or the Java developer-version you should not have any major problems.