# Is there a cheat list/tutorial for Eclipse/NetBeans Dev moving to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, netbeans

I'm a Java developer and I'm very familiar with Eclipse and Netbeans (I've memorized a bunch of shortcuts!). However, my advisor new research uses Windows and C#. So I need to learn C# and move to the "Visual Studio 2010" IDE. So far I'm hating it. I can't get used to it, is there a tutorial or cheat list for helping existing Eclipse/Netbeans devs switch to Visual Studio?

The major things that I mix is the flexibility of eclipse and some key shortcuts like:

- Format-Code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)
- Quick Fix (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>)
- Open Editor -- Navigate quickly (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>)
- Open File of Project -- RegEx (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This chap has done some key bindings that might help you..

[Visual Studio's keybindings for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200499/visual-studios-keybindings-for-eclipse)