# Visual Studio key bindings in Eclipse/PyDev

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, pydev, copy-paste, key-bindings

I am trying to get the Visual Studio key bindings in Eclipse (4.3.2 but applies to others as well), for use in PyDev. (running under Ubuntu 12.04)

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200499/visual-studios-keybindings-for-eclipse/544635#544635), I have installed the C++ dev kit and applied the Visual Studio key bindings theme, which works fine, but the key bindings which are most important to me as still missing.

The functionality that I miss so dearly and would like to reproduce, is the whole-line copy and paste which works as follows:

- With some text selected - normal copy & paste functionality
- With no text selected - copy = copy whole line on which the cursor is currently. Paste then pastes into a newly created line, i.e. it doesn't just jam it in as text, it creates a new line and neatly places your entire line there (above the line the cursor is on, I think)
- With no text selected, cut = cut the entire line. Again, paste neatly inserts the line.

Can anyone either suggest a package that provides this functionality, or alternatively explain how to configure the key bindings manually to achieve this, as I have had a look at the manual config and couldn't achieve what I was looking for.

Alternatively, an experienced user saying that Eclipse simply is not capable of replicating this functionality this would also at least put my mind at rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I found that some amazing person has written a dropin for this. Works perfectly on Ubuntu/Kepler.

https://code.google.com/p/copycutcurrentline/

Many many thanks to the author!