# Set common shortcut keys for Visual Studio, VS code and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, eclipse-plugin

I have been using Visual Studio since last 5-7 years. Now I started using VS Code & Eclipse as well. I am very used to Visual Studio shortcuts.

Can I have same shortcut keys in Eclipse and VSCode as in Visual Studio. I am hopeful that both Eclipse and VS Code should provide setting up own shortcut keys for different operations. It would be difficult to set individual keys for Eclipse and VSCode.

Is there any plugin/file/setting by which I can set easily set most of the shortcuts keys in Eclipse/VS Code as in Visual Studio?

Comment: try this, press ctrl+p and execute following command "ext install vscode-eclipse-keybindings"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about eclipse, but in VS Code there is an extension called [Visual Studio Keymap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vs-keybindings).

Answer (score 0):

i do not think eclipse marketplace (https://marketplace.eclipse.org) has any plugin for keymap of visual studio.
vscode though has a keymap plugin for eclipse, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alphabotsec.vscode-eclipse-keybindings.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Visual Studio key-map to Eclipse by installing the C++ devs tools from within Eclipse. Follow this post to set it up:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10075350/2052295

For VSCode simply install the Visual Studio key-map extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vs-keybindings