# How to add VSCode key-map to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, spring-tool-suite, keymapping

Does anybody know a quick and simple way to get the VSCode key-map in Eclipse?

I primarily work within VSCode, and soon will also be working within STS (Spring Tool Suite) (which is just Eclipse with the STS plugin).

I don't want to have to have to mentally switch between both key-maps constantly.

I was surprised to find that Eclipse doesn't have many options for alternative key-maps.

## Things tried

### Eclipse Marketplace

The Eclipse market place seems to only have one key-map available (IntelliJ) - as seen here:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/keymap

### Visual Studio key-map

I installed the C++ dev tools within Eclipse and enabled the Visual Studio key-map, following the advice here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10075350

This was closer to VSCode's key-map, but still not perfect.

## Current situation

I'm using the Visual Studio key-map, and updating each key that I find is out of sync with the VSCode keymap.
It's not ideal but it's close.

## Ideal scenario

Ideally there would be an extension for this in the Eclipse marketplace, similar to how VSCode has an Eclipse key-map extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alphabotsec.vscode-eclipse-keybindings

Comment: Visual Studio and VS Code are two different products. If you can't find a packages key map that does what you want, you can edit it yourself (or use the Eclipse key map in VS Code and switch over to that).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know they are different products, but their key-maps are very similar so it's closer to VSCode's key-map than eclipse's.

As stated I am currently updating each differing key individually within Eclipse, but this is not ideal.

VSCode is staying as my primary editor so I won't be switching over to the Eclipse key-map.

Comment: Be the one to provide this plug-in via the Eclipse Marketplace (in Eclipse a plug-in is what in VSCode is an extension). Let me know if you need any help with that.

Comment: To anyone willing to accept the challenge: I found two GitHub repos that would be the ideal starting point for creating that desired plugin:

1. [This is an eclipse plugin for visual studio](https://github.com/alphabotsec/vscode-eclipse-keybindings). I know, we need the other way around, but it's a handy lookup for keymap translation.
2. And [this IntelliJIdeaKeymap4Eclipse](https://github.com/IntelliJIdeaKeymap4Eclipse/IntelliJIdeaKeymap4Eclipse) is a keymap plugin for Eclipse you could fork as a starter. - So it more or less boils down to adapting the plugin.xml.

Comment: Anyone up to do it together? [i have started here - Github](https://github.com/YashashGaurav/VSCodeKeymapForEclipse)

Comment: Is this helpful? https://coderedirect.com/questions/134971/visual-studios-keybindings-for-eclipse